How to create Postgres role that is not "on" by default
I'm trying to create a role that is not "on" by default but needs to "turn on" by SET ROLE command. I thought NOINHERIT would be the thing but this is not working (in Postgres v. 15):
create role admin_role NOINHERIT;
create role user login password 'secret';
grant admin_role to user;

create table t(i integer);
alter table revoke insert from user;

-- login as user1
insert into t values (1); -- does happen!!!

I would like user1 to be able to insert data only after SET ROLE admin_role.

You have to use NOINHERIT on the member, not on admin_role.
NOINHERIT means "does not inherit privileges from roles where it is member".
Before PostgreSQL v16, you can only disable all inheritance for a certain role:
CREATE ROLE myuser LOGIN NOINHERIT IN ROLE admin_role;

If you want to inherit from some roles but not for others, use an intermediary role:
CREATE ROLE noinherit_proxy NOLOGIN NOINHERIT IN ROLE admin_role;
CREATE ROLE myuser LOGIN INHERIT IN ROLE noinherit_proxy;

From PostgreSQL v16 on, you can configure inheritance per role you are a member of:
CREATE ROLE myuser LOGIN;
GRANT admin_role TO myuser WITH INHERIT FALSE;


Thanks! "create role user login password 'secret' NOINHERIT" does work. But will this prevent all inheritance for user1, not just the admin_role?

It will prevent all inheritance for the user, yes. Use PostgreSQL v16 or better if you want to configure inheritance per role you are a member of.
